# Hibernate Search - Reindex when associated object is updated

Tags: hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search. I have two classes Article and Publisher.

```
public class Publisher {
    private String name;
}

public class Article {
    private Publisher publisher;
    private String title;
    private String description;
}
```

I want to create an index for a merged field that contains all fields in Article class and *name* field in Publisher class.

A requirement is that when publisher name is changed and persisted to the database, all the articles from that publisher would need to be re-indexed as well. How do I accomplish this? Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use @IndexedEmbedded and @ContainedIn. The former on *publisher* in *Article* and the latter on *articles* in *Publisher*. At the moment you don't have *articles* field in *Publisher*, but to make this work you need a bidirectional link.

Comment: Hi Hardy, very sorry for the long delay. I got dragged onto another task. Thanks a lot for the solution. I tried it out and it worked! I have a follow-up question. If I want to include index from Publisher in multiple classes, and I don't want to reflect the relationships in Publisher class also by adding additional fields and annotating them with @ContainedIn, is there any other way to embed index from Publisher in those classes?

Comment: @HongZ Better ask it in form of another question.